# Тернарный оператор с несколькими действиями

Tags: c++

Как выполнить несколько действий в тернарном операторе? Т.е. как написать что-то такое: условие ? (несколько инструкций) : (несколько инструкций)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть оператор "запятая": в выражении `a, b, c` будут вычислены все значения, возвращено последнее. В тернарном операторе, соответственно, можно им воспользоваться:

```
a = cond ? (foo += 1, baz += bar, baz) : (qwe(), asd(foo, bar), zxc[baz]);
```

Только учтите, что подобная запись кардинально не отличается от записи нескольких операций в одну строчку:

```
if (cond) { foo += 1; baz += bar; a = baz; } else { qwe(); asd(foo, bar); a = zxc[baz]; }
```

По сути, ради экономии на одном присваивании где-то в конце блоков вы превратите код в малочитаемое месиво. Можно попытаться оформить более по-человечески:

```
a = cond
    ? (foo += 1, baz += bar, baz)
    : (qwe(), asd(foo, bar), zxc[baz]);
```

или даже так:

```
a = cond
    ? ( foo += 1,
        baz += bar,
        baz )
    : ( qwe(),
        asd(foo, bar),
        zxc[baz] );
```

Но тогда все преимущества тернарного оператора в виде выразительности теряются. В общем, если вы не работаете над кодом для соревнования по обфускации [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) или не хотите "блеснуть знаниями" перед приятелями, такого кода следует избегать.

Answer (score 3):

Например, разделите инструкции запятыми.

Только учтите, что последние операции в каждой части должны возвращать одинаковый тип, поскольку именно это последнее значение будет результатом всего тернарного оператора.

Comment: Только я бы не рекомендовал так делать практически никогда. Читабельность тернарного оператора и так оставляет желать лучшего частенько, а уж с несколькими операторами это и вовсе выйдет write-only код.

Answer (score 1):

Как вы сами написали, так и используйте.:)

```
условие ? (несколько инструкций) : (несколько инструкций)
```

Только конечно в качестве инструкций должны быть выражения. Если хотите поместить несколько выражения, то можно использовать оператор запятая. Тогда последние "несколько инструкций" должны быть заключены в круглые скобки. Для выражения после вопросительного знака это делать необязательно.

Так же оба выражения должны быть приводимы к общему типу, так как компилятор должен определить тип результата применения тернарного оператора.

Вот простой пример использования тернарного оператора

```
even ? ( even = !even, even_sum += x ) : ( even = !even, odd_sum += x );
```

Comment: Вы точно нигде не опечатались? У вас присваивание значения even в трёх местах. Я мозг сломал.

Comment: @Discord, это C (не хаскель, конечно, но тоже не для слабых на голову)

Comment: @avp Объясните тогда суть операции что ли. Мне кажется, что должно быть что-то в духе `even ? ( even_sum += x, !even ) : ( odd_sum += x, !even );`. Причём, учитывая копипасту, использование тернарного оператора ну очень спорное, даже без учёта читаемости.

Comment: @Discord, тогда уж `even = even ? even_sum += x, !even : odd_sum += x, !even;` Но это же все просто шутки, примеры кода не имеющие никакого смысла.

Comment: @avp Тогда уж `even = even ? even_sum += x : odd_sum += x, !even;`. ;)

Comment: @Discord Поставьте перед этим выражением  ключевое слово return, которое должно возвращать целое число, и все станет на свои места.

Comment: @Discord, ну, Вы наверное имели в виду `even = (even ? (even_sum += x) : (odd_sum += x), !even);`? Но тут пропадает ответ на сам вопрос, о том как писать альтернативные ветви тернарного оператора.

Comment: @avp Да, более того, вроде, можно даже так: `even = ((even ? even_sum : odd_sum) += x), !even);` (лень разбираться с опциональными скобками). И да, это перестаёт быть примером. Но зато смысл более прозрачен. :) Я вот до сих пор не понял, в каком хотя бы отдалённо реалистичном случае можно использовать оригинальный пример. Явно не с чисто локальными переменными, иначе присваивания бесполезны...

Comment: @Discord, на практике? Не знаю. Вот грепнул почти 250000 строк разного кода, увидел там пару тысяч тернарных операторов, а с запятой среди первых нескольких страниц бросилось в глаза только `return nil ? --dst : ({*dst = 0, dst;});`